# How do I generate following matrix?

Tags: r

I have solution matrix(say A) to the indefinite equation x1+x2+x3+x4 = 6. Also, I have another matrix(say B) with columns are

```
0 1 0 1
0 0 1 1
```

I want to generate matrices using rows of A and the columns of B.

For an example, let (2,0,1,3) is the one solution(one row) of the matrix A. Then, the columns of my new matrix are

```
0 0 0 1 1 1 
0 0 1 1 1 1
```

Columns of this new matrix are the multiples of columns of B. i.e., first column 2-times, third column 1-time and fourth column 3-times. I want to use this procedure all the rows of matrix A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `rep`:

```
b <- matrix(c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), nrow = 2)
a <- c(2, 0, 1, 3)

b[, rep(1:ncol(b), a)]
```

if a has many rows:

```
lapply(1:nrow(a), function(i) b[, rep(1:ncol(b), a[i, ])])
```

Comment: That works, but how do I apply this to all the rows of A?

Comment: you can use `lapply`.

Answer (score 0):

```
> B <- rbind(c(0, 1, 0, 1), c( 0, 0, 1, 1))
> A <- rbind(c(2,0,1,3), c(2,0,1,3))

> do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(A), function(jj) t(sapply(1:nrow(B), function(j) do.call(c, lapply(1:4, function(i) rep(B[j,i], A[jj,i]))) ))))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    0    0    1    1    1
[2,]    0    0    1    1    1    1
[3,]    0    0    0    1    1    1
[4,]    0    0    1    1    1    1
```